# Testing create Action using RSpec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am using *RSpec* to test my controller actions and have been successfully tested my `index`, `show`, `edit` actions so far. But for `create` action it is giving me the following error for valid attributes. I'm using rails 5 and ruby 2.5.3. Can't understand what am I doing wrong.

file */spec/factories/leaves.rb*

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :leave do
    id {Faker::Number.between(from = 1, to = 3)}
    user_id {Faker::Number.between(from = 1, to = 3)}
    team_lead_id {Faker::Number.between(from = 1, to = 3)}
    fiscal_year_id {Faker::Number.between(from = 1, to = 3)}
    start_day {Date.today - Faker::Number.number(3).to_i.days}
    end_day {Date.today - Faker::Number.number(3).to_i.days}
    reason {Faker::Lorem.sentences(sentence_count = 3, supplemental = false)}
    status {Faker::Number.between(from = 1, to = 3)}

    factory :invalid_leave do
      user_id nil
    end
  end
end
```

file */spec/controllers/leave_controller_spec.rb*

```
context 'with valid attributes' do
  it 'saves the new leave in the database' do
    leave_params = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:leave)
    expect{ post :create, params: {leave: leave_params}}.to change(Leave,:count).by(1)
  end
  it 'redirects to leave#index' do
    render_template :index
  end
end
```

file */app/controller/leave_controller.rb*

```
def create
    @leave = Leave.new(leave_params)

    if @leave.save
      flash[:notice] = t('leave.leave_create')
      redirect_to leave_index_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = t('leave.leave_create_error')
      redirect_to leave_index_path
    end

  end
```

The error is:

```
LeaveController POST#create with valid attributes saves the new leave in the database
     Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, params: {leave: leave_params}}.to change(Leave,:count).by(1)
       expected `Leave.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/leave_controller_spec.rb:64:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Update** Leave Database

```
create_table "leaves", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "team_lead_id", null: false
    t.integer "fiscal_year_id", null: false
    t.date "start_day", null: false
    t.date "end_day", null: false
    t.text "reason", null: false
    t.integer "status", null: false
    t.string "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Leave Model

```
class Leave < ApplicationRecord
    validates :user_id, :team_lead_id, :fiscal_year_id, :start_day, :end_day, :reason, :status, presence: true
    end
```

Comment: can you post your schema for Leave? you could also change your create action to call @leave.save! and see if it raises any errors when trying to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For Future Reader] I got it to work by doing the fooling in leave_controller_spec.rb file.

```
 describe 'POST#create' do

    context 'with valid attributes' do
      let(:valid_attribute) do
        attributes_for(:leave,
                      user_id: 2,
                      team_lead_id: 3,
                      fiscal_year_id: 2,
                      start_day: '2018-10-10'.to_date,
                      end_day: '2018-10-10'.to_date,
                      reason: 'Sick',
                      status: 2)
      end

      it 'saves the new leave in the database' do

        expect do
          post :create, params: {leave: valid_attribute}
        end.to change(Leave,:count).by(1)
      end
      it 'redirects to leave#index' do
        render_template :index
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be because of `id` which you set in factory. You shouldn't set `id` attribute in factory. That's why number of `Leave` objects didn't change.

Additionally, I assume that you have some relations there - `user_id`, `team_lead_id` etc. If these relations are necessarry to create leave object then you have to create factories for these models, too.

In the end your factory should look like this

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :leave do
    user
    team_lead
    fiscal_year
    start_day {Date.today - Faker::Number.number(3).to_i.days}
    end_day {Date.today - Faker::Number.number(3).to_i.days}
    reason {Faker::Lorem.sentences(sentence_count = 3, supplemental = false)}
    status {Faker::Number.between(from = 1, to = 3)}

    factory :invalid_leave do
      user nil
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: [Factory Bot documentation - associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations)

Comment: There is no relation between them right now. Just wanted to see if I can run  RSpec for post request of a CRUD operation. Thus this advice isn't applicable here. Thank you though.

Comment: I see. It would be useful if you post `Leave` model definition, too. Anyway - have you tried removing `id` attribute from factory?

Comment: Hi, I added the Leave database and model. Also tried removing "id" from factory, but no go.